# Sequences with 0 as every other term

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering what would be the general formula for a sequence given by:

f(0), 0, f(1), 0, f(2), 0, f(3), 0, ...

where the formula for f(n) for any non-negative integer is provided.

Specifically, I want a general formula for a sequence such as:

1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 16, ...

Not stopping there, if the closed form for the first sequence is possible provided a closed for of f(n) is given, I wish to find the closed form for sequence:

f(0), 0, 0, f(1), 0, 0, f(2), ...

and generalize to a case when 'm' zeros are repeated between terms instead of just one or two.

Comment: Formula: $a_i=\frac{1-(-1)^i}{2} f(\frac{i-1}{2})$, then $a_1=f(0)$, $a_2=0$, $a_3=f(1)$ etc.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Would it be a problem if $f$ was defined on Naturals?

Comment: $a_i= \lfloor \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \cos(2\pi\frac{i-1}{m}) \rfloor f(\frac{i-1}{m})$, then $a_1=f(0)$, $a_2=a_3=...=a_m=0$, $a_{m+1}=f(1)$, etc.

Comment: @AkashGaur. One can change $f(\frac{i-1}{m})$ to $f(b_i \frac{i-1}{m})$, where $b_i=\lfloor \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \cos(2\pi\frac{i-1}{m}) \rfloor$.

Comment: One can exclude $\cos$ by using something like $b_i=\lfloor\frac{i-1}{m}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{i-2}{m}\rfloor$.

Comment: My formulas are for $m-1$ zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

For given $m\geq 1$, the sequence with general term
$$a_n=\lfloor|\cos(n\pi/m)|\rfloor$$
satisfies $a_0=a_m=a_{2m}=\dots=1$ and $a_n=0$ when $m\nmid n$.

Multiplying the $a_n$ by a desired factor answers your question.

Comment: There's a small issue with this answer: this annihilates terms of the sequence rather than spacing them out, as in the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit We should be able to extend $f$ to all fractions (as we have a closed formula), then multiply the $a_n$ by $f(n/m)$.

Comment: Perhaps $f(\lfloor n/m\rfloor)$ would be an appropriate extension! The other issue is that the absolute values should be outside the $\cos$ term, as this multiplicand can (and frequently will) be $-1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Indeed!

Answer (score 0):

For $m$ zeroes (indexes of sequence starting from 1):

$$a_i=\left(\left\lfloor \frac{i-1}{m+1}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{i-2}{m+1}\right\rfloor\right)\cdot f\left(\left(\left\lfloor \frac{i-1}{m+1}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{i-2}{m+1}\right\rfloor\right)\cdot\frac{i-1}{m+1}\right)$$